# Replace IMG src from an Array List and display the change in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the old img.src with the value (new img.src) from input fields with Arrays.

The problem I'm stuck at is: the value in the arrays is replaced with the new value but the img.src inside HTML content does not change, so the img stay the same.

```js
function changegallery() {
  var newimgURL = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menuitems > input')).map(imgdata => imgdata.value);
  console.log('newimgURL', newimgURL);
  var oldimgURL = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#gallery > a > img')).map(imgdata => imgdata.src);
  var changeimgURL = oldimgURL.splice(0, oldimgURL.length, ...newimgURL);
  console.log('IMG', oldimgURL);
};
```

```html
<form id="menuitems">
  <input type="url" id="changeimg1" placeholder="URL 1" />
  <input type="url" id="changeimg2" placeholder="URL 2" />
  <input type="url" id="changeimg3" placeholder="URL 3" />
  <input type="url" id="changeimg4" placeholder="URL 4" />
  <Button onClick={changegallery()}>button</Button>
</form>

<div id="gallery">
  <a> <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cn1L4y7j/

Comment: Should the change occur for all 4 images at once? Can it still happen if only 1-2-3 images are loaded (not all 4)? Will there be more than 4 image inputs later, or is this a static case?

Comment: This is just a samle, it could be 1 Input/Image or 10 later. And yes it should change all img.src with new values from inputs on #gallery at once. There will be each image a input, so 1/1.

Comment: So, if there are 4 fields, and the user inserts only 3 images - what would happen? - only 3 images would be present in the gallery, or only 3 images would change their src, and the 4th one would remain the 'old one'?

Comment: Well didnt thinked so far. In case like this , the best option would be to replace the 4th img.src with null/clean value so the old img.src would be replaced.

Comment: So, if the user uploads 3 images, the gallery would contain only the 3 images. Practically, you do not need to change the existing images' scr, but simply remove the existing images in the gallery and create new ones, from the input fields. It's not as much editing existing images, but of clearing the gallery and just pushing the new images to it?

Comment: Yea it could be done with simply createElement, but i wanted to learn little bit more about arrays and tested around to find a solve this way. Even if the user uploads only 3 Image. The full code will delete all images whitch have no valid src url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a second array containing the original image src attributes and then modify that array to contain the new values -- these don't stay as references to the original DOM attributes, it's just an array of strings, so modifying it won't affect the page.  Instead you need to explicitly insert those new values into the DOM.

```js
function changegallery() {

  // read the new URLs
  var newimgURL = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menuitems > input')).map(imgdata => imgdata.value); // note imgdata.value, not the whole image

  // Insert them into the DOM
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#gallery img')).map((img, i) => {
    if (newimgURL[i]) { // don't replace with empty strings
      img.setAttribute("src", newimgURL[i])
    }
  })

};
```

```html
<div id="menuitems">
  <!-- I've included some sample values for demo -->
  <input type="url" id="changeimg1" placeholder="URL 1" value="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
  <input type="url" id="changeimg2" placeholder="URL 2" value="http://placehold.it/101x101"/>
  <input type="url" id="changeimg3" placeholder="URL 3" />
  <input type="url" id="changeimg4" placeholder="URL 4" />
  <Button onClick="changegallery()">button</Button>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
  <a> <img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
  <a> <img id="img4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! The last part made it. Now ive learned a little it more about JS.

Answer (score 0):

**The code below reflects our discussion in the comments to your post:**

Recommendations :

- Would be a nice idea to use some **classes** (in the example, added the imageInput and image classes) to more easily group the desired elements and target them within the DOM (not required, but a good practice and improvement).
- The naming convention of choice should be either camelCaseNaames or underscore_names, not simple alllowercasenamesthatarehardtoread.

```
<form id="menuItems">
    <input class="imageInput" type="url" id="changeimg1" placeholder="URL 1" />
    <input class="imageInput" type="url" id="changeimg2" placeholder="URL 2" />
    <input class="imageInput" type="url" id="changeimg3" placeholder="URL 3" />
    <input class="imageInput" type="url" id="changeimg4" placeholder="URL 4" />
    <button onClick="changegallery()">button</button>
</form>

<div id="gallery">
    <a> <img id="img1" class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
    <a> <img id="img2" class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
    <a> <img id="img3" class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
    <a> <img id="img4" class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"> </a>
</div>
```

The function could be re-written like this:

```
function changegallery() {
    var newImgURLs = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('imageInput')).map(input => input.value);

    var images = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('image'));
    images.map(function(img, i){
        img.src = newImgURLs[i] || null;
    });
};
```

The IDs serve no purpose with the current implementation. If you want for [changeimg1] to specifically change [img1]'s src value, then yes, they are good. If you want for the gallery to simply 'create a new set of images' based on this input, while discarding any unfilled inputs, they are useless.

And if the inputs do not affect the individual images (if only 3 images are added, only 3 images are shown in the gallery, as per discussed in the comments), you should simply re-create the gallery when uploading a new set of images:

```
function changegallery() {
    var gallery = document.getElementsById('gallery');
    gallery.innerHTML = '';

    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('imageInput')).map(function(input, i) {
        if (input.value != '') {
            gallery.innerHTML += '<a> <img id="img'+i+'" class="image" src="'+input.value+'"> </a> '
        }
    });
};
```